# Paging my Wordpress PHP Query

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a query that returns Properties for Rent / Sale on their respective pages, no matter what I try I can not get the query to successfully page.

One of thepages I want to employ pagination is http://www.urbanvision.org.uk/services/property-services/properties-for-sale/.

I want numbered pagination and attempted to use WP Navi but my PHP messed up and I was getting an error message when trying to access the published page.

My Current code is:

```
<?php
$featuredPosts = new WP_Query();
$featuredPosts->query('showposts=100&cat=13');
while ($featuredPosts->have_posts()) : $featuredPosts->the_post(); ?>

<div class="literaturedescription">

<?php
$prop_det_url = get_field('property_details_url');
if($prop_det_url!=''){ ?>

<a href="<?php echo $prop_det_url; ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php the_field('property_title'); ?>">
<img src="<?php the_field('property_thumbnail'); ?>" width="220px" height="150px" alt="<?php the_field('property_title'); ?>" /></a>

<?php } else { ?>

<a href="<?php the_field('property_details'); ?>" title="<?php the_field('property_title'); ?>" target="_blank">
<img src="<?php the_field('property_thumbnail'); ?>" width="220px" height="150px" alt="<?php the_field('property_title'); ?>" /></a>

<?php } ?>

<p><strong><?php the_field('property_title'); ?></strong><br /><?php the_field('property_excerpt'); ?> <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;"><?php the_field('property_status'); ?></span>


<?php
$prop_det_url = get_field('property_details_url');
if($prop_det_url!=''){ ?>

<br /><a href="<?php echo $prop_det_url; ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php the_field('property_title'); ?>">&gt; &gt; View Details</a></p><br />

<?php } else { ?>

<br /><a href="<?php the_field('property_details'); ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php the_field('property_title'); ?>">&gt; &gt; View Details</a></p><br />

<?php } ?>


</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

It's getting to the point that we are going to be adding more and more properties and ideally would like pages of 10 or 20 posts per page.

---

Update to show Code that I have tried to implement:

```
<?php
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1
$featuredPosts = new WP_Query();
$featuredPosts = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'cat' => 13, 'paged' => $paged);
while ($featuredPosts->have_posts()) : $featuredPosts->the_post(); ?>

<div class="literaturedescription">

<?php
$prop_det_url = get_field('property_details_url');
if($prop_det_url!=''){ ?>

<a href="<?php echo $prop_det_url; ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php the_field('property_title'); ?>">
<img src="<?php the_field('property_thumbnail'); ?>" width="220px" height="150px" alt="<?php the_field('property_title'); ?>" /></a>

<?php } else { ?>

<a href="<?php the_field('property_details'); ?>" title="<?php the_field('property_title'); ?>" target="_blank">
<img src="<?php the_field('property_thumbnail'); ?>" width="220px" height="150px" alt="<?php the_field('property_title'); ?>" /></a>

<?php } ?>

<p><strong><?php the_field('property_title'); ?></strong><br /><?php the_field('property_excerpt'); ?> <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;"><?php the_field('property_status'); ?></span>


<?php
$prop_det_url = get_field('property_details_url');
if($prop_det_url!=''){ ?>

<br /><a href="<?php echo $prop_det_url; ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php the_field('property_title'); ?>">&gt; &gt; View Details</a></p><br />

<?php } else { ?>

<br /><a href="<?php the_field('property_details'); ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php the_field('property_title'); ?>">&gt; &gt; View Details</a></p><br />

<?php } ?>


</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata() ?>

<?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $featuredPosts) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add pagination to your query first.

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1

$featuredPosts = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'cat' => 13, 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

after endwhile call `wp_reset_postdata()`

then for wp_pagenavi:

```
wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $featuredPosts) );
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris_O. I have added your suggestion into my code but get the following error 'HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfil the request.' I've updated my answer with the code changes I made.

Comment: Turn on WP_DEBUG  in wp-config.php add define('WP_DEBUG', true); and see if you can get more info about the error.  You also need to remove the extra `$featuredPosts = new WP_Query();`

Comment: Thanks, it says that there is a syntax error at on the line with the following code `$featuredPosts = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'cat' => 13, 'paged' => $paged);`

Comment: Thanks for your help :) got it working there is also a `;` required for the paged line `$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;`